# How do you enable a class to affect the class it is instantiated from?

Tags: javascript, class

If I have a class, and an instance of that class instantiates a different class as one of its properties, how can that property affect the parent's properties?  e.g. in the following example I want the Gpa class to be able to modify the Person it belongs to.

```
class Person {
  constructor (name, gpa) {
    this.name = name;
    this.happynessHistory = [];
    this.gpa = new Gpa(gpa);
  }
}
class Gpa {
  constructor (startingGpa) {
    this.score = startingGpa;
  }
  updateGpa (newGpa) {
    this.score = newGpa:
    if (this.score < 3.0) {
      // push 'true' to the Person's happynessHistory array
    } else {
      // push 'false' to the Person's happynessHistory array
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? You may be looking for an event emitter or some such which would let you listen for events coming from the Gpa object without causing the Gpa object to be completely intertwined with the Person object. Example - `this.gpa.on('scoreUpdate', [handle])`. There's a term for this that I can't remember right now, but basically.. you're currently throwing water in the face of lots of programming theories :)

Comment: @Stephen the reason for this architecture is that there will be multiple properties on the `Person` that the `.happynessHistory` could be affected by.  I am open to other patterns, but want to be able to create classes like `Gpa` to keep code compartmentalized and so it can be shared.  For example, if instead of Person there was both `HighSchoolStudent` and `JuniorHighStudent` and both needed to be able to have a `gpa` which affected their `.happynessHistory`.  I'll look into events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the `Person` instance to the `Gpa` instance when creating it:

```js
class Person {
  constructor (name, gpa) {
    this.name = name;
    this.happynessHistory = [];
    this.gpa = new Gpa(gpa, this); // pass parent
  }
}
class Gpa {
  constructor (startingGpa, person) {
    this.score = startingGpa;
    this.person = person;
  }
  updateGpa (newGpa) {
    this.score = newGpa;
    this.person.happynessHistory.push(this.score < 3.0);
  }
}

var p = new Person("Test", 4.0);
p.gpa.updateGpa(2.0);
console.log(p.happynessHistory);
```

That's the straightforward answer; a better way is to have a method in the Person class that updates its Gpa instance and appends to the array.

Answer (score 0):

You want to affect a `person`, but you have no instance of `Person` to start with.

What you are trying to do will make more sense in a delegation model.

For example,

```js
const Person = {
  init(name, gpa) {
    this.name = name;
    this.gpa = Object.create(Gpa);
    this.gpa.init(gpa, this);
    this.happinessHistory = [];
  },
};

const Gpa = {
  init(startingGpa, person) {
    this.score = startingGpa;
    this.person = person;
  },
  updateGpa(newGpa) {
    this.score = newGpa;
    if (this.score < 3.0) {
      this.person.happinessHistory.push(true);
    } else {
      this.person.happinessHistory.push(false);
    }
  },
};

var john = Object.create(Person);
john.init('John', 3.3);
var amy = Object.create(Person);
amy.init('Amy', 2.2);
amy.gpa.updateGpa(1.0);
console.log(amy.happinessHistory);
```